# Creating a table with a Foreign Key in SQL by My-SQL Workbench gives Error 1215

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I need the SQL for my classes, and I started training. I created microdb in AMAZON RDS, and downloaded MySQL Workbench. I successfully connected to my database, however, when I tried to add Figure 3.1 from the Silberschatz - Database system concepts, it failed to create tables with a foreign key with a famous error 1215. Here, the code:

```
create table department
(dept_name varchar (20),
building varchar (15),
budget numeric (12,2),
primary key (dept_name));
create table course
(course_id varchar (7),
title varchar (50),
dept_name varchar (20),
credits numeric (2,0),
primary key (course_id),
foreign key (dept_name) references department);
create table instructor
(ID varchar (5),
name varchar (20) not null,
dept_name varchar (20),
salary numeric (8,2),
primary key (ID),
foreign key (dept_name) references department);
create table section
(course_id varchar(8),
sec_id varchar (8),
semester varchar (6),
year numeric (4,0),
building varchar (15),
room_number varchar (7),
time_slot_id varchar (4),
primary key (course_id, sec_id, semester, year),
foreign key (course_id) references course);
create table teaches
(ID varchar (5),
course_id varchar (8),
sec_id varchar (8),
semester varchar (6),
year numeric (4,0),
primary key (ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year),
foreign key (course_id, sec_id, semester, year) references section,
foreign key (ID) references instructor);
```

How should I handle this? The MySQL version is 5.7.2.

With regards, Ulvi

Comment: None of the FKs are defined correctly please see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html for correct syntax.

Comment: @P.Salmon Thanks for the answer! It is strange to add wrong code in the book.

Anyway, when I added the attribute like foreign key (dept_name) references department(dept_name), all worked.

Comment: " It is strange to add wrong code in the book." -- Well, I don't think the book's code is specific to MySQL. The SQL dialects spoken by different DBMS may vary. [Oracle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e51335c952cc743758805f5d33241e87) for example accepts the syntax as given. However the more verbose syntax of  `REFRENCES <table> (<columns>)` is clearer and accepted by any major DBMS and should have been used preferably in a book about DBMS in general therefore.